# django-two-factor-auth's user.is_verified() returns False on subdomains

Tags: python, django, subdomain, two-factor-authentication, django-two-factor-auth

I am facing this strange issue, I have posted it [here](https://github.com/jazzband/django-two-factor-auth/issues/518) already but didn't get any response yet.

I am using ***django-two-factor-auth*** in my Django application, Everything works fine in the local environment but getting an issue on the production server.

My application is tenant-based and I am using subdomains for each tenant, for example on the production server,

> My application => xyz.com
>
> User with tenant name "a" after login gets redirected to => a.xyz.com
>
> User with tenant name "b" after login gets redirected to => b.xyz.com

When redirected to a subdomain I am getting this issue that user.is_verified() always returns False even if 2fa is enabled for the user. I am using user.is_valrified() for showing enable/disable 2fa buttons.

If I remove the subdomain redirection, it works fine and returns True if 2fa is enabled for a user.

**My Environments**

> Browser and version: Google Chrome Version 103.0.5060.114
>
> Python version: 3.8.10
>
> Django version: 2.2.0
>
> django-otp version: 0.9.4
>
> django-two-factor-auth version: 1.12.1

Note: I have debugged this enough that I know this is happening due to sub-domains